# program run but stopped and shows java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java

I have a problem with my program it compiles and run but when I go into a case first it does what the case says then it stop and give me this messages:

> "Exception int thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at testVessel.main(testVessel.java:165)

as I think the problem is int the case 3 from the first switch.
Here is the main class:

```
    class testVessel
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        String name,idioktName,skafos,temp1;
        double length,width,ektopisma,maxspeed,max,ektop;
        int etos,epilogh,size=0,thesi,i=0,o,a,year;
        boolean shmaia=true,flag;
        Vessel[] skafoi=new Vessel[10];
        for(;shmaia;)
           { 
               System.out.println("lista epilogwn");
               System.out.println("1.eisagwgh stoixeiwn skafous");
               System.out.println("2.emfanish stoixeiwn skafous");
               System.out.println("3.emfanish oloklhrou tou pinaka");
               System.out.println("4.telos");
               System.out.println("dwste epilogh(1-4):");
               epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
               if(epilogh==4)shmaia=true;

               switch(epilogh)
               {

                    case 1 :
                           System.out.println("dwste onoma skafous:");
                           name=UserInput.getString();
                           System.out.println("dwste mhkos:");

                           flag=true;
                           length=0;
                           for(;flag;)
                              {
                                 length=UserInput.getDouble();
                                 if(length>=0 && length<=1000)flag=false;
                                 else
                                     System.out.println("mh apodekta oria xanadokimaste\n");
                              }                               
                           System.out.println("dwste platos:");
                           width=UserInput.getDouble();
                           System.out.println("dwste ektopisma:");
                           flag=true;
                           ektopisma=0;
                           for(;flag;)
                              {
                                 ektopisma=UserInput.getDouble();
                                 if(ektopisma>=0 && ektopisma<=150000)flag=false;
                                 else
                                     System.out.println("mh apodekta oria xanadokimaste\n");
                              }
                           System.out.println("dwste etos kataskeuhs:");
                           etos=UserInput.getInteger();
                           System.out.println("dwste megisth taxhtyta:");
                           maxspeed=UserInput.getDouble();
                           System.out.println("dwste onoma idioktith:");
                           idioktName=UserInput.getString();
                           skafoi[i]=new Vessel(name,length,width,ektopisma,etos,maxspeed,idioktName);
                           i++;
                           size++;
                           break;
                    case 2 :
                           if(size==0)System.out.println("den uparxoun skafoi sth lista xanadokismaste \n");
                           if(size!=0)
                           {System.out.println("epilogh pediou anazhthshs");
                           System.out.println("1.onoma skafous");
                           System.out.println("2.etos kataskeuhs"); 
                           System.out.println("3.ektopisma");
                           System.out.println("4.megisto mhkos skafous");
                           System.out.println("5.epistrodh sthn arxikh lista epilogwn");
                           System.out.println("dwste epilogh(1-5):");
                           epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
                           switch(epilogh)
                           {
                                case 1:
                                       MyUtils.epiloghMethodou();
                                       epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
                                       switch(epilogh)
                                       {
                                            case 1:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste onoma skafous");
                                                   skafos=UserInput.getString();
                                                   thesi=MyUtils.seqSearch(skafoi,skafos);
                                                   System.out.println(skafoi[thesi].EmfanishOlwn());
                                                   break;
                                            case 2:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste onoma skafous");
                                                   skafos=UserInput.getString();
                           thesi=MyUtils.binSearch(skafoi,skafos,size);
                                                   System.out.println(skafoi[thesi].EmfanishOlwn());
                                                   break;
                                            case 3:
                                                   break;
                                            default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ... Eisagete ari8mo 1-3\n");
                                       }break;
                                 case 2:
                                       MyUtils.epiloghMethodou();
                                       epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
                                       switch(epilogh)
                                       {
                                           case 1:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste etos kataskeuhs");
                                                   year=UserInput.getInteger();
                                                   MyUtils.seqSearch(skafoi,year,size);
                                                   break;
                                           case 2:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste etos kataskeuhs");
                                                   year=UserInput.getInteger();
                                                   MyUtils.binSearch(skafoi,year,size);
                                                  break;
                                           case 3: 
                                                  break;
                                           default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ... Eisagete ari8mo 1-3\n");
                                        }break;
                                 case 3:
                                       MyUtils.epiloghMethodou();
                                       epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
                                       switch(epilogh)
                                       {
                                           case 1:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste ektopisma");
                                                   ektop=UserInput.getDouble();
                                                   MyUtils.seqSearch(skafoi,ektop,size);
                                                   break;
                                           case 2:
                                                   System.out.println("dwste ektopisma");
                                                   ektop=UserInput.getDouble();
                                                   MyUtils.binSearch(skafoi,ektop,size);
                                                   break;
                                           case 3:
                                                   break;
                                           default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ... Eisagete ari8mo 1-3\n");
                                       }break;
                                 case 4:
                                        MyUtils.epiloghMethodou();
                                       epilogh=UserInput.getInteger();
                                       max=0;
                                       a=0;
                                       switch(epilogh)
                                       {
                                           case 1:
                                                   MyUtils.seqSearch(skafoi,max,size,a);
                                                   System.out.println("h max taxhthta einai:"+max);
                                                   break;

                                           case 2:
                                                   MyUtils.binSearch(skafoi,max,size);
                                                   System.out.println("h max taxhthta einai:"+max);
                                                   break;
                                           case 3:
                                                   break;
                                           default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ... Eisagete ari8mo 1-3\n");
                                       }
                                 case 5:
                                       break;
                                       default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ... Eisagete ari8mo 1-5\n");}

                            }

                            break;


                    case 3:
                            if(size!=0)
                               {for(i=0;i<skafoi.length;i++)
                                  {
                                      System.out.println(skafoi[i].EmfanishOlwn());
                                  }
                               }
                             if(size==0)
                                 {System.out.println();
                                  System.out.println("den uparxoun skafoi sth lista");
                                  System.out.println();} 
                             break;
                    case 4:
                              System.out.println("telos programmatos");
                              shmaia=false;
                              break;
                              default: System.out.print("\n\tLathos epilogi methodou ...  Eisagete ari8mo 1-4\n");
       } if(size==10)shmaia=false;
 }
 }
 }
```

and here are the secondary:

```
  class MyUtils
  { 

 public static  void seqSearch(Vessel[] a,int key,int size)
 {
      int x=0;
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(a[i].getetos()==key)
          {System.out.println(a[i].EmfanishOlwn());
           x++;}
        if(x==0)System.out.println("den uparxoun skafoi autou tou etous");
 }
 public static int seqSearch(Vessel[] a,String key)
 {
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i].getname()==key)
           return i;
      return -1;
 }
 public static void seqSearch(Vessel[] a,double key,int size)
 {
      int x=0;
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         if(a[i].getektopisma()==key)
            {System.out.println(a[i].EmfanishOlwn());
            x++;}
         if(x==0)System.out.println("den uparxoun skafoi me tetoio ektopisma");
 }
 public static void seqSearch(Vessel[] a,double max,int size,int l)
 { 
         l=0;
         max=0;
         for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
           if(a[i].getmaxspeed()>max)max=a[i].getmaxspeed(); 
 }
 public static int binSearch(Vessel[] a,String key,int size)
 {
       int left=0,right=size-1;
       return binarySearch(a,key,left,right);
 } 
 private static int binarySearch(Vessel[] numbers,String key,int left,int right)
 {
      int mid,pos=-1;
      while(pos==-1 && left<=right)
       {
           mid=(left+right)/2;
           if(numbers[mid].getname().compareTo(key)>0)
             right=mid-1;
           else
             if(numbers[mid].getname().compareTo(key)<0)
               left=mid+1;
             else
               pos=mid;
       }
      return pos;
  }
 public static void binSearch(Vessel[] a,int key,int size)
 { 


      int left=0,right=size-1;
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
          if(a[i].getetos()==a[binarySearch(a,key,left,right)].getetos())System.out.println(a[i].EmfanishOlwn());
 }
 private static int binarySearch(Vessel[] numbers,int key,int left,int right)
 {
      int mid,pos=-1;
      while(pos==-1 && left<=right)
       {
           mid=(left+right)/2;
           if(key<numbers[mid].getetos())
             right=mid-1;
           else
             if(key>numbers[mid].getetos())
               left=mid+1;
             else
               pos=mid;
       }
      return pos;
  }
  public static void binSearch(Vessel[] a,double key,int size)
  {

       int left=0,right=size-1;
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
          if(a[i].getektopisma()==a[binarySearch(a,key,left,right)].getektopisma())System.out.println(a[i].EmfanishOlwn());
  }              

  private static int binarySearch(Vessel[] numbers,double key,int left,int right)
  {
      int mid,pos=-1;
      while(pos==-1 && left<=right)
       {
           mid=(left+right)/2;
           if(key<numbers[mid].getektopisma())
             right=mid-1;
           else
             if(key>numbers[mid].getektopisma())
               left=mid+1;
             else
               pos=mid;
       }
      return pos;
   }



 public static void epiloghMethodou()
 {
    System.out.println("epilogh methodou anazhthshs"); 
    System.out.println("1.seiriakh anazhthsh");
    System.out.println("2.duadiki anazhthsh");
    System.out.println("3.epistrofh sthn epilogh pediou anazhthshs");
    System.out.println("dwste epilogh(1-3):");

 }
 } 

  class Vessel
{
private String name;
private double length;
private double width;
private double ektopisma;
private int etos;
private double maxspeed;
private String idiokName;
Vessel(String n,double l,double w,double e,int et,double ms,String cn)
{
    name=n;
    length=l;
    width=w;
    ektopisma=e;
    etos=et;
    maxspeed=ms;
    idiokName=cn;
}
public String getname()
{
    return name;
}
public double getlength()
{ 
    return length;
}
public double getwidth()
{
    return width;
}
public double getektopisma()
{
    return ektopisma;
}
public int getetos()
{
    return etos;
}
public double getmaxspeed()
{
    return maxspeed;
}
public String getidiokName()
{
    return idiokName;
}
public String EmfanishOlwn()
{
    String toString=("to onoma einai: "+name+"\n");
    toString+=("to mhkos einai: "+length+"\n");
    toString+=("to platos einai: "+width+"\n");
    toString+=("to ektopisma einai: "+ektopisma+"\n");
    toString+=("to etos einai: "+etos+"\n");
    toString+=("h megisth taxhtyta einai: "+maxspeed+"\n");
    toString+=("to onoma tou idiokthth einai: "+idiokName+"\n");
    return toString; 
 } 
 }

 import java.util.Scanner;
 class UserInput
 {
 public static int getInteger()
 {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 try
 {
 int x;
 x = input.nextInt();
 return x;
 }
 catch (Exception e )
 {
 System.out.println("Error");
 return -1;
 }
 }
 public static double getDouble()
 {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 try{
 double x;
 x = input.nextDouble();
 return x;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 System.out.println("Error");
 return -1;
 }
 }
 public static float getFloat()
 {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 try{
 float x;
 x = input.nextFloat();
 return x;
 }
 catch (Exception e){
 System.out.println("Error");
 return -1;
 }
 }
 public static String getString()
 {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 String x;
 x = input.nextLine();
 return x;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements of this array are `null`.

`Vessel[] skafoi=new Vessel[10];`

Make sure you initialize them first by
calling an appropriate constructor.

When you get to this line:
`System.out.println(skafoi[i].EmfanishOlwn());`
not all of them are initialized so you get
the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i put in the loop of case 3 insead of i<skafoi.length  i<size and now there is no problem thank vary much :)